# How to make text run on image?

Tags: ffmpeg, scrolling

I have a photo and a text page. I want to make a video with a background image that I have and the text will run on that photo. Please help me with ffmpeg

Comment: Sounds like you want some video editing software... not ffmpeg.

Comment: You can see clips: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2aY5y3kC2M

Comment: You really need to add some more detail so to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Basic method is

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image \
       -vf drawtext=textfile='yourtextfile':x=X:y=h-t*(h/D),format=yuv420p \
       -t T out.mp4
```

`yourtextfile` is a plaintext UTF-8 file.

You will have to see how long the text takes to scroll across and use that in the `-t T` option (e.g. `-t 30` to make a 30 second video), otherwise ffmpeg will keep going indefinitely.

`X` should be replaced with a value that represents horizontal position. `x=100` for 100 pixels from left-edge. `x=w-500` for 100 pixels from right-edge.

In the y expression, `h/D` controls the scrolling speed. `D` is the number of seconds a line takes to reach from the bottom to the top.

Consult the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) documentation for more details, like font selection and styling.